# You're using the staticfiles app without having set the required STATIC_URL setting - Django

Tags: python, django

I have 5 months of experience in django and I can not just find the solution of the error which I encounter.
I think it depends on frontend files, I can not deal with static files right now
Recently, I have been building a chat app called PyChatt

Whole project available on Github [here](https://github.com/AbdusamadAbdullaxanov/PyChatt)

traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\pytho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 1016, in 
_bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\pytho\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\threading.py", line 953, in 
run
self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
File "D:\python_projects\Webogram\Internal\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 
64, in wrapper
fn(*args, **kwargs)
File "D:\python_projects\Webogram\Internal\lib\site- 
packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 157, in inner_run
handler = self.get_handler(*args, **options)
File "D:\python_projects\Webogram\Internal\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\management\commands\runserver.py", line 35, in get_handler
return StaticFilesHandler(handler)
File "D:\python_projects\Webogram\Internal\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 75, in __init__
self.base_url = urlparse(self.get_base_url())
File "D:\python_projects\Webogram\Internal\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\handlers.py", line 30, in get_base_url
utils.check_settings()
File "D:\python_projects\Webogram\Internal\lib\site- 
packages\django\contrib\staticfiles\utils.py", line 49, in check_settings
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: You're using the staticfiles app without having 
set the required STATIC_URL setting.
```

and settings.py:

```
from pathlib import Path
import os

BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent
SECRET_KEY = 'django-insecure-pke21+-&vpt2=ka6$a_=x5vz-@#_)o^ro#eet+h03sy&y-l+8w'
DEBUG = True
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*"]

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'UsersAuthentication',
    'MessageHandleEngine',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'config.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [BASE_DIR.joinpath("templates")],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'config.wsgi.application'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'Chat-Database',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        "PASSWORD": "20051205",
        "USER": "postgres"
    }
}
AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

MEDIA_URL = "/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "media")
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"),
)

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'
USE_I18N = True
USE_TZ = True
STATIC_URl = "/static/"
DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> STATIC_URl = "/static/"

should be STATIC_URL

Comment: Oooooh, crab, Only a typo????

Comment: pycharm font be like :-(